Having trouble declaring friend classes using macros and template metaprogramming
I'm having trouble declaring friend classes using macros and template metaprogramming. The specific error is C2065: "N": undeclared identifier, which is usually because the identifier N is not handled correctly when the macro is expanded."N": undeclared identifier dufomap_run line 74.
#ifndef UFO_MAP_HPP
#define UFO_MAP_HPP

// UFO
#include <ios>
#include <ufo/map/octree/octree.hpp>

namespace ufo
{
// NOTE: Remove this when it is possible to friend varidic number of classes
#define REPEAT_2(M, N)   M(N) M(N + 1)
#define REPEAT_4(M, N)   REPEAT_2(M, N) REPEAT_2(M, N + 2)
#define REPEAT_8(M, N)   REPEAT_4(M, N) REPEAT_4(M, N + 4)
#define REPEAT_16(M, N)  REPEAT_8(M, N) REPEAT_8(M, N + 8)
#define REPEAT_32(M, N)  REPEAT_16(M, N) REPEAT_16(M, N + 16)
#define REPEAT_64(M, N)  REPEAT_32(M, N) REPEAT_32(M, N + 32)
#define REPEAT_128(M, N) REPEAT_64(M, N) REPEAT_64(M, N + 64)

// All your base are belong to us
template <template <class, std::size_t> class... Maps>
class OctreeMap
    : public Octree<OctreeMap<Maps...>>
    , public Maps<OctreeMap<Maps...>, 8>...
{
 protected:
    //
    // Friends
    //
     friend Octree<OctreeMap>;
#define FRIEND(N)      
            friend std::tuple_element_t<std::min<std::size_t>(static_cast<std::size_t>(N+1),   
            sizeof...(Maps)),                         
            std::tuple<void, Maps<OctreeMap, 8>...>>;
                 // 调用 REPEAT_128 宏
    REPEAT_128(FRIEND, 0)
            
 public:
    //
    // Constructors
    //

    OctreeMap(node_size_t leaf_node_size = 0.1, depth_t depth_levels = 17)
        : Octree<OctreeMap>(leaf_node_size, depth_levels)
    {
    }

    OctreeMap(std::filesystem::path const& file) : OctreeMap(0.1, 17)
    {
        Octree<OctreeMap>::read(file);
    }

    OctreeMap(std::istream& in) : OctreeMap(0.1, 17) { Octree<OctreeMap>::read(in); }

    OctreeMap(ReadBuffer& in) : OctreeMap(0.1, 17) { Octree<OctreeMap>::read(in); }

    OctreeMap(OctreeMap const& other) = default;

    OctreeMap(OctreeMap&& other) = default;

    template <template <class, std::size_t> class... Maps2>
    OctreeMap(OctreeMap<Maps2...> const& other) : Octree<OctreeMap>(other)
    {
        (initilize<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>>(other), ...);
        (init<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>, OctreeMap<Maps2...>::mapType()>(
             Octree<OctreeMap>::numNodesAllocated() / 8),
         ...);
    }

    template <template <class, std::size_t> class... Maps2>
    OctreeMap(OctreeMap<Maps2...>&& other) : Octree<OctreeMap>(other)
    {
        (initilize<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>>(std::move(other)), ...);
        (init<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>, OctreeMap<Maps2...>::mapType()>(
             Octree<OctreeMap>::numNodesAllocated() / 8),
         ...);
    }

    OctreeMap& operator=(OctreeMap const& rhs) = default;

    OctreeMap& operator=(OctreeMap&& rhs) = default;

    template <template <class, std::size_t> class... Maps2>
    OctreeMap& operator=(OctreeMap<Maps2...> const& rhs)
    {
        Octree<OctreeMap>::operator=(rhs);
        (initilize<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>>(rhs), ...);
        (init<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>, OctreeMap<Maps2...>::mapType()>(
             Octree<OctreeMap>::numNodesAllocated() / 8),
         ...);
        return *this;
    }

    template <template <class, std::size_t> class... Maps2>
    OctreeMap& operator=(OctreeMap<Maps2...>&& rhs)
    {
        Octree<OctreeMap>::operator=(rhs);
        (initilize<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>>(std::move(rhs)), ...);
        (init<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>, OctreeMap<Maps2...>::mapType()>(
             Octree<OctreeMap>::numNodesAllocated() / 8),
         ...);
        return *this;
    }

    //
    // Swap
    //

    void swap(OctreeMap& other) noexcept(noexcept(
        Octree<OctreeMap>::swap(other)) && noexcept((Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::swap(other), ...)))
    {
        Octree<OctreeMap>::swap(other);
        (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::swap(other), ...);
    }

    //
    // Map type
    //

    [[nodiscard]] static constexpr mt_t mapType() noexcept
    {
        return (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::mapType() | ...);
    }

 protected:
    //
    // Init
    //

    template <class Map, mt_t MT>
    void init(std::size_t size)
    {
        if constexpr (0 == (MT & Map::mapType())) {
            Map::resize(1);
            Map::initRoot();
            Map::resize(size);
        }
    }

    //
    // Create node block
    //

    void createNodeBlock(Index node) { (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::createNodeBlock(node), ...); }

    //
    // Apply Permutation
    //

    void applyPermutation(Permutation const& perm)
    {
        (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::applyPermutation(perm), ...);
    }

    //
    // Resize
    //

    void resize(std::size_t new_size) { (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::resize(new_size), ...); }

    //
    // Reserve
    //

    void reserveImpl(std::size_t new_cap)
    {
        (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::reserveImpl(new_cap), ...);
    }

    //
    // Initialize root
    //

    void initRoot() { (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::initRoot(), ...); }

    //
    // Fill
    //

    void fill(Index node, pos_t children)
    {
        (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::fill(node, children), ...);
    }

    //
    // Clear
    //

    void clearImpl(pos_t nodes) { (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::clearImpl(nodes), ...); }

    //
    // Shrink to fit
    //

    void shrinkToFitImpl() { (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::shrinkToFit(), ...); }

    //
    // Update node
    //

    void updateNode(Index node, pos_t children)
    {
        (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::updateNode(node, children), ...);
    }

    //
    // Is prunable
    //

    [[nodiscard]] bool isPrunable(pos_t nodes) const
    {
        return (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::isPrunable(nodes) && ...);
    }

    //
    // Memory node block
    //

    [[nodiscard]] static constexpr std::size_t memoryNodeBlock() noexcept
    {
        return (Maps<OctreeMap, 8>::memoryNodeBlock() + ...);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] std::size_t serializedSize(std::ranges::input_range auto r, bool compress,
                                             mt_t data) const
    {
        return (serializedSize<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>>(r, compress, data) + ...);
    }

    void readNodes(std::istream& in, std::ranges::input_range auto r, bool const compressed,
                   mt_t map_types)
    {
        auto cur_pos = in.tellg();
        in.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
        auto end_pos = in.tellg();
        in.seekg(cur_pos);

        map_types &= mapType();

        Buffer buf;
        Buffer compress_buf;
        while (in.tellg() != end_pos && in.good()) {
            MapType       mt;
            std::uint64_t data_size;

            in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&mt), sizeof(mt));
            in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data_size), sizeof(data_size));

            if (mt & map_types) {
                (readNodes<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>>(in, buf, compress_buf, r, mt, data_size,
                                               compressed) ||
                 ...);
            } else {
                // Skip forward
                in.seekg(static_cast<std::istream::off_type>(data_size), std::istream::cur);
            }
        }
    }

    void readNodes(ReadBuffer& in, std::ranges::input_range auto r, bool const compressed,
                   mt_t map_types)
    {
        map_types &= mapType();

        Buffer compress_buf;
        while (in.readIndex() < in.size()) {
            MapType       mt;
            std::uint64_t data_size;

            in.read(&mt, sizeof(mt));
            in.read(&data_size, sizeof(data_size));

            std::uint64_t next_index = in.readIndex() + data_size;

            if (mt & map_types) {
                (readNodes<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>>(in, compress_buf, r, mt, data_size, compressed) ||
                 ...);
            }

            // Skip forward
            in.setReadIndex(next_index);
        }
    }

    void writeNodes(std::ostream& out, std::ranges::input_range auto r, bool const compress,
                    mt_t const map_types, int const compression_acceleration_level,
                    int const compression_level) const
    {
        Buffer buf;
        (writeNodes<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>>(out, buf, r, compress, map_types,
                                        compression_acceleration_level, compression_level),
         ...);
    }

    void writeNodes(WriteBuffer& out, std::ranges::input_range auto r, bool const compress,
                    mt_t const map_types, int const compression_acceleration_level,
                    int const compression_level) const
    {
        out.reserve(out.size() + serializedSize(r, compress, map_types));
        (writeNodes<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>>(out, r, compress, map_types,
                                        compression_acceleration_level, compression_level),
         ...);
    }

    //
    // Dot file info
    //

    std::ostream& dotFileInfo(std::ostream& out, Index node, mt_t map_types) const
    {
        (dotFileInfo<Maps<OctreeMap, 8>>(out, node, map_types), ...);
        return out;
    }

 private:
    //
    // Initilize
    //

    template <class Map, class Map2>
    void initilize(Map2 const& other)
    {
        if constexpr (Map::mapType() & Map2::mapType()) {
            Map::operator=(other);
        }
    }

    template <class Map, class Map2>
    void initlize(Map2&& other)
    {
        if constexpr (Map::mapType() & Map2::mapType()) {
            Map::operator=(std::forward<Map2>(other));
        }
    }

    //
    // Input/output (read/write)
    //

    template <class Map>
    std::size_t serializedSize(std::ranges::input_range auto r, bool compress,
                               mt_t map_types) const
    {
        if (Map::mapType() & map_types) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (compress) {
            return sizeof(MapType) + sizeof(std::uint64_t) + sizeof(std::uint64_t) +
                   maxSizeCompressed(Map::serializedSize(r));
        } else {
            return sizeof(MapType) + sizeof(std::uint64_t) + Map::serializedSize(r);
        }
    }

    template <class Map>
    bool readNodes(std::istream& in, Buffer& buf, Buffer& compress_buf,
                   std::ranges::input_range auto r, MapType const mt,
                   uint64_t const data_size, bool const compressed)
    {
        if (Map::mapType() != mt) {
            return false;
        }

        buf.clear();
        // TODO: Implement better (should probably be resize?)
        buf.reserve(data_size);
        in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf.data()), static_cast<std::streamsize>(data_size));
        return readNodes(buf, compress_buf, r, mt, data_size, compressed);
    }

    template <class Map>
    bool readNodes(ReadBuffer& in, Buffer& compress_buf, std::ranges::input_range auto r,
                   MapType const mt, uint64_t const data_size, bool const compressed)
    {
        if (Map::mapType() != mt) {
            return false;
        }

        if (compressed) {
            compress_buf.clear();

            std::uint64_t uncompressed_size;
            in.read(&uncompressed_size, sizeof(uncompressed_size));

            decompressData(in, compress_buf, uncompressed_size);

            Map::readNodes(compress_buf, r);
        } else {
            Map::readNodes(in, r);
        }

        return true;
    }

    template <class Map>
    void writeNodes(std::ostream& out, Buffer& buf, std::ranges::input_range auto r,
                    bool const compress, mt_t const map_types,
                    int const compression_acceleration_level,
                    int const compression_level) const
    {
        if (0 == (Map::mapType() & map_types)) {
            return;
        }

        buf.clear();
        writeNodes(buf, r, compress, compression_acceleration_level, compression_level);

        if (!buf.empty()) {
            out.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(buf.data()),
                      static_cast<std::streamsize>(buf.size()));
        }
    }

    template <class Map>
    void writeNodes(WriteBuffer& out, std::ranges::input_range auto r, bool const compress,
                    mt_t const map_types, int const compression_acceleration_level,
                    int const compression_level) const
    {
        constexpr MapType mt = Map::mapType();
        if constexpr (MapType::NONE == mt) {
            return;
        }

        if (0 == (mt & map_types)) {
            return;
        }

        out.write(&mt, sizeof(mt));

        std::uint64_t size;
        auto          size_index = out.writeIndex();
        out.setWriteIndex(size_index + sizeof(size));

        if (compress) {
            Buffer data;
            data.reserve(Map::serializedSize(r));
            Map::writeNodes(data, r);

            compressData(data, out, compression_acceleration_level, compression_level);
        } else {
            Map::writeNodes(out, r);
        }

        auto cur_index = out.writeIndex();
        size           = cur_index - (size_index + sizeof(size));
        out.setWriteIndex(size_index);
        out.write(&size, sizeof(size));
        out.setWriteIndex(cur_index);
    }

    //
    // Dot file info
    //

    template <class Map>
    std::ostream& dotFileInfo(std::ostream& out, Index node, mt_t map_types) const
    {
        if (0 == (Map::mapType() & map_types)) {
            return out;
        }

        out << "<br/>";

        return Map::dotFileInfo(out, node);
    }
};
}  // namespace ufo

#endif  // UFO_MAP_HPP

But there is no such error in the Linux environment. This error only appears in Windows.
The error occurred during the expansion of macro FRIEND(N). The N here was not declared correctly during macro expansion.

The problem arises here.“friend std::tuple_element_t<std::minstd::size_t(static_caststd::size_t(N+1),
sizeof...(Maps)),
std::tuple<void, Maps<OctreeMap, 8>...>>;”

It seems you are trying to define a multiline macro. You need to end each line but the last with a backslash \ . As written, you define a macro FRIEND(N) that expands to the empty list of tokens; followed by literal code friend std::tuple_element_t ... which mentions N, which is an undeclared identifier. Again, friend std::tuple_element_t... is not part of the macro definition, which ends at the end of the line on which #define appears.

@IgorTandetnik,thanks,I will try it.
